# Platform Module System feature of Java 9 adopted by the next release of Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-9

The final release of Java EE 8 started on 18 September 2017 according to the [JCP official page](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=366). So maybe it is to early to wonder, although the question is justifiable:

Is there any information or discussion about the adoption of the Platform Module System feature by the next Java EE release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE standards development has been moved to the Eclipse Foundation and will now be called EE4J (Eclipse Enterprise For Java).

https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/opening-up-ee-update

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j/charter

Nothing has been announced about how the standards will be developed (i.e. will Eclipse use the JCP, some international standards body like OASIS or create their own).  Once the next version of the standard starts to be developed, how JPMS will be integrated will be discussed.

Comment: Your answer is clear enough. Although we could be wondering if there is a need of JPMS feature in EE4J next release and if so, is Eclipse willing to integrate it?

Comment: It would certainly be logical for Eclipse to do so.  I will be at Devoxx next week so will chat to some people who are more involved with Java EE/EE4J than I am to see if I can get a better picture of what they're thinking.